# Harmonics on periodic functions

Tags: transform

Ok I need to understand how some harmonic calculations work to apply some transforms.

If I have a periodic functiion f(x). And I have the values of that function for several values of x (say x goes from 0 to 359) so I have

f(0)=3
f(1)=5
... etc

So if I'm asked to take the max of those values without the first harmonic. How can I do this? and what does it mean?

Thanks

Edit: Here is the pdf of the method I'm implementing, it's the only one I found publicaly available. There are tables of functionals on the paper which are applioed to texture analysis of images. The result of the second set of functionals is a periodic function and on the third set of functionales there are a couple of functionales where you need to get i of xi so that xi is the max or min value without the first harmonic. http://pdf.aminer.org/000/067/295/texture_classification_with_thousands_of_features.pdf

Comment: Do you know the period of the function? and if so, how is it related to $360$, the _number_ of values of $x$ for which you know the value of $f(x)$

Comment: The period is basically 2*Pi

Comment: each value of x is equally spaced on that period

Comment: You should give more background to increase your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. To me the answer to Dilip's question about the period is still quite unclear. What does it mean if "each value of x is equally spaced in that period"? If the period is $2\pi$ then your samples cover a range of about 57 periods, is that right? What about the "equally spaced" property?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very knowledgeable on harmonic analysis. I'm implementing an algorithm and the literature asks me to get the max/min indexes of the value of a series of values of a periodic function without the first harmonic. I think the values correspond to values of x within the period of the function but I'm not sure. The result of the calculations give me exactly 360 values.

Comment: I added the link to the paper above. A couple of the functionals on the third table are the ones where I must get a value without the first harmonic.

Comment: All right, let's try something easier. In your $360$ values of $f(n), n = 0,1,2,\ldots,359$ are there two values that are the same? That is, if there is _some_ integer $m$ and some _other_ integer $n$ such that $f(m) = f(n)$, what are $m$ and $n$? If there are several such equal values, can you tell is what the corresponding arguments of $f(\cdot)$ are? A possible answer might be "$f(n)$ has the same value for $n = 3, 23, 43, 63, \ldots, 343$" or "I have gone through all $360$ numbers and they are all different"

Comment: Ok, there are not two values that are the same but there are some similar ones. The calculations are done several times and include floating point operations so I checked one instance. An example of similar values are f(19)=41.122719, f(111)=41.162392, f(330)=41.028347. There are several instances with similar values and the values range from f(75)=47.498971 which is the maximun value to f(275)=14.800286 which is the minimun value.

Comment: Find the $360$-point discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of $$(f(0),f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(359)) \longrightarrow (F(0),F(1),\ldots,F(359)).$$ Now set $F(1)$ and $F(359)$ to $0$. Warning: if you are using MATLAB, the bins are numbered 1 through 360 so set both bin#2 and bin #360 to $0$. Compute the $360$-point inverse Discrete Fourier transform of what is left. The result is $f(\cdot)$ with the first harmonic removed.  Find the maximum value of the iDFT output to find the largest value of $f$ with the first harmonic removed.  Warning: do not use zero-padding to get a "convenient" length for an FFT.

Comment: Sounds similar to [THD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_harmonic_distortion) analysis of audio waveforms, though N=360 makes me think you're doing some kind of vibration analysis of a rotating machine which is sampled every 1 degree of rotation?

Comment: Thank you very much Dilip. I'm going to try and implement that. I'm programming in C not Matlab so I need to do all the twiking myself.

Comment: @endolith I'm applying some transforms over some images for texture analysis. I have to sample each image with traces rotating over it in 360 degress so each of this 360 numbers represent the result of transforms applied to the traces on each angle of rotation so yeah it could be something like that.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sorry to bother you again with this. Like I mentioned I'm doing this in C, so I'm using the fftw3 libraries (www.fftw.org/fftw3.pdf). I'm using what is described in section 2.5.1 to do what you suggested. In that section it says: <Continues below>

Comment: "For a halfcomplex array hc[n], the kth component thus has its real
part in hc[k] and its imaginary part in hc[n-k], with the exception of k == 0 or n/2 (the
latter only if n is even)—in these two cases, the imaginary part is zero due to symmetries
of the real-input DFT, and is not stored. Thus, the r2hc transform of n real values is a
halfcomplex array of length n, and vice versa for hc2r."

Comment: The halfcomplex array is the output of the DFT. I just want to make sure that what you described about setting F(0) and F(359) to 0 applies in this case without a problem. Meaning I have to do hc[0]=0 and hc[359]=0? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the $F(0)$ and the $F(359)$ that you need to zero out are not explicitly available, but have values $hc[1]+j\cdot hc[359]$ and $hc[1]-j\cdot hc[359]$. So if you zero out $hc[1]$ and $hc[359]$, the inverse fftw program (as long as it is also set to interpret $hc[\cdot]$ as a half-complex array of length $360$) will get the answer you seem to want.